# Showing that the integral of sin(πt)dt is divergent?

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

Having trouble showing why this integral diverges.

$\int_\infty^{-\infty} sin(πt)dt$

How do I write this integral as a limit?

Comment: What kind of integral do you use? (Generalized) Riemann? Lebesgue? I think the argument will look slightly different depending on that.

Comment: @mickep Lebesgue

Comment: OK, then use that $\int f$ and $\int |f|$ are either both convergent or divergent. Then, use the fact that $\int_0^{\pi}|\sin t|\,dt=2$. Summing, you will get something that diverges.

Comment: @mickep thank you so much, but how did you get the limits to be from 0 to pi? is that from a theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int^{2n}_{-n}\sin(\pi t)dt=-\frac{1+(-1)^n}{\pi}
$$
and that alternates between $0$ and $-2/\pi$ as you take the limit $n\to\infty$
($n$ is odd in the above).

Answer (score 0):

As

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_{2n}^{2n+\frac{1}{2}}\sin(\pi t)dt=\frac{1}{\pi}\;(\neq 0)$$

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\sin(\pi t)dt$$ diverges by Cauchy test and so does

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(\pi t)dt.$$